# How to host ASP.NET WebAPI application without enabling CORS, but allowing access by any domain?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, cors, cross-domain

I am trying to get a new project up and running and I need it to call existing web services I have written in a different project. Eventually my project will be moved into the same webapp as the web services, so this will not be run in production this way.

I would like to allow the web services to be called from any domain. I have set the following custom headers in my web.config:

```
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

This does show up in IIS Manager, but seems to have no affect on the call. I am still receiving the following error when I call the service:

```
"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."
```

As I have said, I only need this to work in development. My web service project is not compatible with the Microsoft CORS library and that is why I can't just enable CORS.

EDIT
I am using asp.net WebAPI2 to provide REST endpoints for my applications. I just need to know how to configure them to allow any domain to access them without using CORS.

Comment: You need to access your web services from your web api application? is that your question?

Comment: So I have two web servers: one on port 80 and one on port 4200. The web services are hosted on port 80 and the application is running on 4200. They are completely  different apps.

Comment: You should be able to add the web services references into your web api project.

Comment: @Hackerman No I can't. My web services are hosted in asp.net, but I am running my app via Angular CLI. I don't need to find a way to combine the projects, I need a way to make this scenario work.

Comment: You should remove then the `asp.net-web-api` tag and add the `angular` tag instead...and also try to add as much details as possible into your question...I'll give it a shot later!

Comment: I removed the tag. How is not applicable? Isn’t this a question about how to configure them?  Another way to look at it is that I want to configure my services so that anyone can call them, period. I just don’t want to use CORS if possible. Does the second app confuse the question? I just didn’t want someone to tell me not to do it because it isn’t secure. I am aware of the security implications.

Comment: You need to add details for example: `Currently my web services are WCF webservices, or they are ASMX web services, or they are OWIN self hosted web services`...that is because every one has different configurations...the more details you put into your question, the better.

Answer (score 1):

The one solution you can implement is to create a proxy js like a facade on your API's domain.

For example, you have a WebAPI domain api.example.com
So, create a js-library (facade) that implements the logic of usage of that API.
The url will be http://api.example.com/script.js

So, include that file into each project and use your API through that js-facade.